# Word for Following The Shift In "Immigration Patterns"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, paired-word-requests

I'm looking for an effective word or words to replace immigration pattern. I use the phrase in a previous sentence, and would not like to reuse it again. I can't think of a better word choice to replace it with though, and fine with not using the immigration pattern at all, but I would like to see other options first.

Here's the text.

> "This decline is primarily due to changing immigration patterns. Up until the 1980s, immigration to Sweden predominantly comprised of  European labor migrants; however, since then non-European refugees and asylum seekers have begun to make up larger shares of the immigrant population. Following the shift in immigration pattern, labor market integration rates have deteriorated and welfare dependency increased among immigrants."

To be frank, I'm not a fan of the phrase in the first place, and if anyone could help come up with a different choice of words, I will be grateful. Thx :)

Comment: "immigration pattern" appears to me to be a defined phrase - it means immigration that has some complex profile of characteristics (the nature of which may only be implicit or vague in the context).

Answer (score 1):

**Immigration Demographics** fits, as in the title to this document.

[U.S. Immigration Demographics and Immigrant Integration](https://www.brookings.edu/on-the-record/u-s-immigration-demographics-and-immigrant-integration/)

And I suggest replacing *comprised* with some other word such as *consisted*.

Answer (score 0):

> Following the shift in migration, ..."

In context, this would be know as human immigration and would allow you to use other synonyms.

migration  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/migration)

> n.
>   1. The act or an instance of migrating.
>   2. A group migrating together.

*These shifts*, *these movements* could also work for you.